# How do I sort with both depth and y-axis in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, python

Continuing my [misadventures in pyOpenGL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134510/pyopengl-draw-loop-slow-with-just-1500-items-to-draw), I've refactored the whole thing to use 4 buffers:

1. tile vertices - all drawn at the start, probably never modified
2. tile texture co-ords - not modified often (but enables support for animated tiles later)
3. sprite vertices - modified often as sprites move around the map
4. sprite texture co-ords - modified often as sprites animate

My draw loop binds each buffer, and calls `drawArrays()` twice. I have enabled depth testing, and clear the depth buffer on each draw:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DEPTH)
...
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
...
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

For the moment, I've hard-coded the z coordinate for each of the things I'm drawing, just to be sure they're definitely in the right order - grass tiles are at `0.9`, the tree (4 tiles) is set to -1.0 and the sprites are at 0.0. This is what I get:

[image: sprites occluded by grass tiles]

In a previous attempt to build this engine without openGL, I was using Tkinter canvas images, which ended up very slow. To get the draw order right, I had to sort all the objects by their y-coordinate plus their z-coordinate, because it is all on a 2D plane. I want something similar, here. I don't understand why the grass tiles cause this problem, when they should be drawn right at the back. `GL_DEPTH_TEST` is definitely enabled - if I disable it by commenting out the `glEnable()` call, the sprites are drawn on top of everything (including on top of the trees). I want an illusion of depth by being able to walk behind high-sticking-up objects.

---

I've continued hacking away at this, and I've gotten a little further by modifying my shader:

```
fragment_shader = shaders.compileShader("""
    uniform sampler2D u_image;

    varying vec2 v_texCoords;

    void main() 
    {
        vec4 tex = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoords);
        if(tex.a < 1.0)
          discard;
        gl_FragColor = tex; //texture2D(u_image, v_texCoords);
    }
""", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
```

By checking for transparent pixels and throwing them away, I get a lot closer to my goal, however it is still not *quite* right, and I do not know how to fix it.

[image: Transparency from the shader]  [image]   [image]

The wizard is at `z:-0.5`, and the tree trunk is at `z:-0.2`; it *is* doing what I'm telling it to do, just not what I *want* it to do. If I put them on the same z-level, the trunk is drawn over the wizard when he stands in front of the tree, and correctly when he stands behind it:

[image]

I don't just want depth sorting, I also want to sort on the *y-axis*. How can I do this in OpenGL?

Comment: `GL_DEPTH_TEST` is definitely your friend in this situation and should be enabled. What if you use the y coordinate at the "foot" (i.e. lowest y-value) of each sprite to define the z coordinate of each sprite? That is take the y value of each sprite, which vary from (0, height_of_your_screen) and map this to a z value between your `zNear` and `zFar` planes (probably (-1, 1)). Since grass is always in the back behind everything else, set its z-coordinate to the `zFar` value.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need

1. An orthogonal Projection Matrix.

   In fixed pipeline openGL: `glOrtho(0, screen_width, screen_height, 0, -(1<<16), 1<<16)`
2. A wrapper function similar to: `DrawSprite(int x, int y, int z, Rect texcoords)` This function will add vertices to the vertex buffer you're using - with the exact Z coordinate specified for the whole sprite.
3. Coordinate system that looks like this (e.g. identity matrix for modelview):

[image]

4. Alpha testing `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);` `glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.9f);` - this is to make sure that transparent pixels DO NOT get written to depth buffer.
5. Depth testing `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` The default depth function is the one we want.
6. Finally when you draw a sprite you call `DrawSprite(sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.y, texturecoords_rect)`. As you see, the `sprite.y` coordinate is used as the Z coordinate and corresponds to value written to depth buffer.
7. Sprite coordinates correspond to *feet* of the object.

[image]

The RED DOT, is the sprite X, Y coordinate. So the Z value has to correspond to Y coordinate of the RED DOT. Also in this case the tree is a sprite and not part of the tilemap (directly).

Or you could have the red dot be right in the middle (but that doesn't really matter for the correct Z ordering):

[image]

No manual sorting is necessary here, all the *sorting* is done using depth testing!

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I came across `glOrtho()` when I was researching my problem, but it always seemed to be accompanied with a "we don't do it like this anymore", but mostly without a "we do it like this instead". I think I've finally got it working, I'll probably write an answer with what I wrote. Your note about flipping the y-axis was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @MalphasWats You can replicate `glOrtho()` quite easily - it creates a projection matrix such that our coordinate system - where one unit is one pixel - maps right to so called *normalized device coordinates* where each component x,y,z is from -1 to 1. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml

Comment: In fact, you don't even have to use a "projection matrix" in the vertex shader, just scale each vertex by (2/screen_width,2/screen_height,-2/zrange) and then add (-1,-1,0) to it