# glViewport() Win10 doesn't draw new parts

Tags: opengl, python

I've been [steadily working](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134809/getting-draw-depth-order-right-in-opengl-tile-engine) through building a basic 2D tile framework in python.

I'm trying to use modern openGL so I have a simple shader and some vertex buffers and it's mostly doing what I want so far. I have a Scene with a method for centering the viewport on a Sprite:

```
def centre_viewport(self, x, y):
    x = -x+self.viewport_width//2
    y = y-self.viewport_height//2
    if x > 0:
        x = 0
    if y < 0:
        y = 0
    if x - self.viewport_width < -self.width:
        x = -self.width + self.viewport_width
    if y + self.viewport_height > self.height:
        y = self.height - self.viewport_height
    self.viewport_x = x
    self.viewport_y = y
    glViewport(x, y, self.viewport_width, self.viewport_height)
```

`self.viewport_width` and `_height` are set when a scene is added to the window, so they have the same dimensions as whatever window is created.

In my test game, the scene width and height are twice the window dimensions of `704x512`. Everything works fine on my main mac development machine. On my work windows machine though, when the sprite moves and causes the scene to scroll, the previously hidden parts of the scene are not drawn:

[image: viewport issue]

My draw loop is very simple:

```
def _draw(self):
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.sprite_vertex_buffer)
    glVertexAttribPointer(self.vertices, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.sprite_texture_buffer)
    glVertexAttribPointer(self.tex_coords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, None)

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, self.sprite_vertex_count)


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.tile_vertex_buffer)
    glVertexAttribPointer(self.vertices, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.tile_texture_buffer)
    glVertexAttribPointer(self.tex_coords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, None)

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, self.tile_vertex_count)
```

and as mentioned, it works fine on my mac.

Is `glViewport()` the appropriate way to be doing this, and why isn't it working properly on windows?

Comment: Don't tell me you create a new array buffer every time you draw something

Comment: Nope, the buffers are created when the scene is first created, then each one is bound and drawn in the `_draw()` method. There is an `_update()` method that runs through each sprite to update the positions/tex coords for each sprite (hence the separate tile/sprite buffers) and they are each loaded with new data using `glBufferSubData()` so that the buffers aren't recreated. That part was all learnt from [this question :)](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134510/pyopengl-draw-loop-slow-with-just-1500-items-to-draw?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Please don't take this as a personal attack, but I'm really new to all this and I'm seeing so many comments like this, but so little explanation of how I *should* be doing it instead, I really have no idea. I've diligently worked through various examples and tutorials and whatnot, trying to piece together everything as best I can. Once I try to go beyond drawing a rotating cube though, everything falls apart because it's really hard to find concrete **this is the best way to do this because**. I know every application is different, but there seems to be a set of unwritten rules.

Comment: Okay, then just 1 thing, `glGetAttribLocation` is very costy, you should only call it once and save the result somewhere

Comment: Thank you - I'm planning to write all my findings up eventually for clueless noobs that follow :) I've updated my `_draw()` method to take those out!

Comment: Does your Mac have a Retina display? On my MacBook Pro, I always got a back buffer size that was 2x the window size. This may have something to do with your problem. (That won't happen on Windows, or at least hasn't yet to me.)

Comment: hmm, that's an interesting thought - my mac is an older MBP so no retina, however, my work machine is a surface pro 3 which *does* have a 'HiDPI' screen and runs at 1.5x scaling. I also suspect it has an older version of OpenGL, which I need to check at some point.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my problem by doing things differently. I don't really want this to be the accepted answer because it doesn't answer why `glViewport()` isn't working properly on my Windows machine. However, I have a working viewport now, using a translation matrix:

first I modified my shader to accept a matrix and apply it to each vertex:

```
        attribute vec3 a_position;
        attribute vec2 a_texCoords;

        uniform mat4 t_matrix;

        varying vec2 v_texCoords; 

        void main() 
        { 
            gl_Position = t_matrix * vec4(a_position, 1); 

            v_texCoords = a_texCoords; 
        }
```

in my Scene class, I hook into the matrix as part of my initialisation method:

```
self.transform_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(self.shader_program, "t_matrix")
```

and then whenever the viewport is moved, I update the matrix:

```
def centre_viewport(self, x, y):
    x = -x+self.viewport_width//2
    y = y-self.viewport_height//2
    if x > 0:
        x = 0
    if y < 0:
        y = 0
    if x - self.viewport_width < -self.width:
        x = -self.width + self.viewport_width
    if y + self.viewport_height > self.height:
        y = self.height - self.viewport_height
    self.viewport_x = x
    self.viewport_y = y
    #glViewport(x, y, self.viewport_width, self.viewport_height)

    self.viewport_matrix = [
                                1, 0, 0, self.viewport_x * 2.0 / self.viewport_width,
                                0, 1, 0, self.viewport_y * 2.0 / self.viewport_height,
                                0, 0, 1, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 1,
                           ]
```

The matrix then gets uploaded to the GPU each time around the `_draw()` loop:

```
def _draw(self):

    glUniformMatrix4fv(self.transform_matrix, 1, True, self.viewport_matrix)

    ...
```

Notice that the matrix is transposed (3rd parameter set `True`), I could have constructed the matrix the right way around I suppose, but I think it looks tidier this way!

Ultimately this is a better way to do what I want anyway, because it gives me the option of translating the `z` axis too, if I want to do things with very tall towers later or something. I can probably offload pixel->ndc coordinate calculations by adding a projection matrix later if things need to be faster (not sure it'll make enough difference to worry about, but the option is there).